# Integrating a function in the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^4$ using angular coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, polar-coordinates

Let $f: B_1(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(v) = f(x,y,z,w) = \tilde{f}(|(x,y)|, |(z,w)|)$, for some $\tilde{f}$. I have to prove there's a positive constant $C$ such that
$$
\int_{B} f(v) dv = C \int_{D} \tilde{f}(s,t) s\, t\, ds dt,
$$
where $D = \{(s,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :, s,t \geq 0, |(s,t)| < 1\}$.

**My attempt:** Consider $T : Q := [0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,2\pi] \times [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ definied by
$$T(s,t, \theta, \varphi) = (s \cos \theta, s \sin \theta, t cos\varphi, t \sin \varphi).$$
So $B = T(Q)$. One can easily prove that $|J T| = st$.  Thus
$$
\int_B f(v) dv = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \tilde{f}(|(s \cos \theta, s \sin \theta)|, |(t cos\varphi, t \sin \varphi)|) s\, t\, d \theta \varphi ds dt.
$$
In other words,
$$
\int_B f(v) dv = (2\pi)^2  \int_0^1  \int_0^1 \tilde{f} (s, t) s \, t \, d s dt.
$$
**My question** is how to see that $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \tilde{f} (s, t) s \, t \, d s dt$ equals, up to a constant, to $\int_{D} \tilde{f}(s,t) s\, t\, ds dt$.

Comment: If you want $B=T(Q)$, you should have $s^2 + t^2 \le 1$ rather than $(s,t) \in [0,1]^2$, shouldn't you?

Comment: Thank you. This was my mistake.